# Adding google-play-service source to my android application

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I want to add Google-map to my android application and I followed this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#overview 
but it shows me an error. which is: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
when I searched in Google trying to solve the problem, I found that I have to do these steps:

1. In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
2. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
3. Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
4. From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
5. When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
6. Click OK to close the Properties window.

But when I Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog which is step number 3, I could not choose any library project. i.e the list is empty.

I don't know if I should add @integer.xml file? If so, how to do that? I am sorry but I am really new to eclipse. 
So, could anyone help me please:(

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have the Play Services project in your workspace, as explained here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Now make sure that it is a Library Project. Right-click the play-services project -> Properties -> Android and make sure you check **Is Library** after the list of build targets.

After that, redo the steps you listed. In Step 4 Play Services will be in the list.